# Simple asymptotic analysis problem

Tags: asymptotics

I came across a problem that I tried to formalize as follows:

Let say i have two functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ such that for $t \rightarrow t_0$
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}
 \;y(t) \rightarrow -\infty \\
 x(t) \rightarrow -\infty \\
 y(t) = o(x(t))
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Shouldn't be in such case $ 2^{y(t)} = o(2^{x(t)})$ ? If yes I struggle to prove it is true... otherwise what can we say instead? What about if we don't assume $y(t),x(t) \rightarrow - \infty$?

PS. Just to be clear.. by $y(t) = o(x(t))$ I mean that $\frac{y(t)}{x(t)} = 0$, for $t \rightarrow t_0$.

Answer (score 1):

No, $ 2^{y(t)} = O(2^{x(t)})$ is false.

Consider the example

$$ \left\{ \begin{array}  y(t) = -\frac1{|t-t_0|} \\  x(t) = -\frac2{|t-t_0|} \\ y(t) = \frac12 x(t) = O(x(t)) \end{array} \right. $$
But if we let $u = \frac1{|t-t_0|}$, then 
$2^{-u}$ is not $O(2^{-2u})$, although it is $O(\sqrt{2^{-2u}})$:  as $u\to\infty$, the ratio of $2^{-u}$  to $2^{-2u}$ exceeds any constant $C$.

Comment: I'm sorry but why in your example $y = O(x)$? should the ratio $y / x$ be 0 for $t \rightarrow t_0$?

Comment: CHeck your definition of the "big-O" notation -- it means that there is a constant $C$ and some distance $\epsilon>0$ such that $|t-t_0|<\epsilon \implies y(t) < Cx(t)$.  And that is obviously true; for example, take $C=3$.

Comment: What I meant was $\frac{y(t)}{x(t)} \rightarrow 0 \;\; t \rightarrow t_0$